# Add help to python module

Tags: python, documentation, spyder

I use Spyder and for example numpy. Then, when I use some function, like
np.interp(), object inspector gives me help about this function. How to put documentation into my modules which will be displayed in Spyder's object inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be python documentation comments:

```
"""
This module contains methods and classes
"""

class class_:
    """
    This class is well... a class
    """
    def method(self, in_):
        """
        This method takes one argument: in_ and returns it
        """
        return in_
```